# If examples has too many columns ，every row will be too long to read！

Tags: karate

If examples has too many columns ，every row will be too long to read！

```
Feature:

  Background:

  Scenario Outline:
    * match '<msg>' == <prefix> + ',' + '<end>'
    Examples:
      | prefix | end   | msg         |
      | hello  | mike  | hello,mike  |
      | hello  | jerry | hello,jerry |
```

Could it be like that：

```
Feature:

  Background:
    Examples:
    | prefix |
    | hello  |

  Scenario Outline:
    * match '<msg>' == <prefix> + ',' + '<end>'
    Examples:
      | end   | msg         |
      | mike  | hello,mike  |
      | jerry | hello,jerry |
```

I want to divide the examples in several parts， or set a base examples before Outline.What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

karate address this in many different ways in its latest versions `0.9.X`, Let see

1. As you asked we can define the `Examples:` tables before `Scenario Outline:` using [table](https://github.com/intuit/karate#table) in karate,

```
Feature: my feature
  Background: BG
    * table myExample
      | prefix | end   | msg         |
      | 'hello'  | 'mike'  | 'hello,mike'  |
      | 'hello'  | 'jerry' | 'hello,jerry' |

  Scenario Outline: SOW
    * match '<msg>' == '<prefix>' + ',' + '<end>'
    Examples:
    | myExample |
```

the same can be kept in another feature file and read it in this feature file, but don't complicate as we have some other solutions coming below..

2.karate sees all these `table`, `Examples:` as array of JSON's

typically you example above will be represented as,

```
[
  {
    "prefix": "hello",
    "end": "mike",
    "msg": "hello,mike"
  },
  {
    "prefix": "hello",
    "end": "jerry",
    "msg": "hello,jerry"
  }
]
```

so karate allows you to define these `Examples` also from `JSON` or `csv` formats using karate's [dynamic scenario outline feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline)

if you feel like you examples are too large to accommodate in your feature file keep it in a `csv` file and  do read in your `Examples`

```
Feature: my feature
  Background: BG
    * def myExample = read("myExample.csv")

  Scenario Outline: SOW
    * match '<msg>' == '<prefix>' + ',' + '<end>'
    Examples:
    | myExample |
```

The same applies to JSON also, providing data as JSON array.