# Scenario Outline in Karate for multi-line JSON

Tags: karate

How to use scenario outline to iterate for a JSON which is more than single cell

https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-cucumber-way

Data.json

```
[{
    "address": {
        "addressLine1": "ttes",
        "addressLine2": "Test",
        "addressLine3": "Test",
        "addressType": "business",
        "city": "TEST",
        "company": "TEST",
        "country": "TEST",
        "state": "TEST",
        "postalCode": "XXXX"
    },
    "name": {
        "firstName": "TEST",
        "lastName": "TEST",
        "middleInit": "T",
        "title": "Mr."
    },
    "phone": {
        "phoneExtension": "1234",
        "phoneNumber": "999999999",
        "phoneType": "mobile"
    },
    "email": {
        "emailAddress": "TEST@TEST.com"
    }
},
{
    "address": {
        "addressLine1": "ttes1",
        "addressLine2": "Test1",
        "addressLine3": "Test1",
        "addressType": "business",
        "city": "TEST1",
        "company": "TEST1",
        "country": "TEST1",
        "state": "TEST1",
        "postalCode": "XXXX"
    },
    "name": {
        "firstName": "TEST1",
        "lastName": "TEST1",
        "middleInit": "T",
        "title": "Mr."
    },
    "phone": {
        "phoneExtension": "1234",
        "phoneNumber": "999999999",
        "phoneType": "mobile"
    },
    "email": {
        "emailAddress": "TEST@TEST1.com"
    }
}]
```

====

```
Feature: Read from File

Background:
* def Testdata = read('Data.json')

Scenario Outline: [1] Test with multiple records on JSON

Given url_stg
And path 'test','test' 
And request Testdata
When method POST  

Examples:
|Testdata   |
```

Comment: Updated as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer it in this documentation as it very straight forward for your case.

[dynamic-scenario-outline](https://github.com/intuit/karate/#dynamic-scenario-outline)

refer to this answer for different ways of providing data to `Scenario Outline:`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135752/8615449

Comment: I need to build a request with JSON nested array , I would not be referring to any JSON element here

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. However, I have `JSON` stored in a `key-value pair` and  I want to pass that in `request payload`.                                                                                                            


                                                                             
`{
    "sample_key":[{"email":"karate@test.com","country":"IND"}.{"email":"karate2@test.com","country":"AUS"}]
}`

Please suggest. Thank you !!

Comment: is `{"email":"karate@test.com","country":"IND"}` your single `payload` ? have you refered this link https://github.com/intuit/karate/#dynamic-scenario-outline >